# Data went missing when converting const char * to std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, zlib

In this example,

*just giving the const char * value  as an input(ie::test one)

*converting const char * to std::string

*passed the value of std::string to compress the string

*string compressed and can able to see the value of the compressed String

*eg::compressed String::x�+I-.Q��Ko#

*Now converting the std::string of compressed data to const char *...

*when i 'm doing this step ,getting only 75% of the data.few data's went missing.

Eg:: x�+I-.Q��K

*what shall i need to do inorder to get the whole data?

*Can someone help me in this regard?

```
      int main ( int argc,char *argv[] )

    {

        const char *str = "test one";
        int length = 0;

        std::string compressionString(str);//converting char * to std::string
        cout << "compressionString::" << compressionString<< endl;

        while(*(str+length))
        length++; //length of char *

        cout << "Length of entered string:: " <<length << endl;

        std::string compStr = compress_string(compressionString);//Compress the string using compress_string()

        cout << "compressed String::"<<compStr << endl;

        const char* m_pcompCharptr = compStr.c_str();

        cout << "Compressed string char* length::"<< sizeof(m_pcompCharptr) <<endl;
        cout << "Compressed value which is present in char * is :: " <<m_pcompCharptr << endl;

        cout << "Compressed String length:: " << compStr.length() << endl;
       int iCompLen = compStr.length();

        cout << "iCompLen::" << iCompLen << endl;

        std::string decompressionString(m_pcompCharptr);//converting const char* to std::string

        std::string decompStr = decompress_string(decompressionString);

        cout << "decompStr::" << decompStr << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output::

compressionString::test one

Length of entered string:: 8

compressed String::x�+I-.Q��Ko#

Compressed string char* levgth::8

Compressed value which is present in char * is :: x�+I-.Q��K

Compressed String length:: 16

iCompLen::16

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Exception during zlib decompression: (-5) 
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: I wouldn't put a compressed string in a `string`. Especially because it may no longer be considered a string.

Comment: I'm guessing that there's a null byte in the compressed string. Does it work if you use `std::string decompressionString(m_pcompCharptr, compStr.size());` in the fourth-to-last line?

Comment: The question is pretty much incomprehensible to me. Please use full sentences and improve the formatting to clearly mark code fragments as such, etc.

Comment: Probably you have an embedded NUL byte (0x00). `std::string` can contain NUL bytes, but plain old `const char *` cannot, because they use that value as a terminator. You should really use a `std::vector<char>` instead of a `std::string` from binary data.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hmmm strlen(str)+1 include the terminator. the while is a odd way to count the length but it will work. I would replace it anyway.

Comment: `sizeof(m_pcompCharptr)` is the size of the pointer, not the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this...

```
const char* m_pcompCharptr = compStr.c_str();
```

...you get a `const char*` to the first character in `compStr`, which itself has no notion or record of length/size.  If you then construct a string using the `const char*` from above...

```
std::string decompressionString(m_pcompCharptr);
```

The `std::string` constructor's overload for `const char*` relies on ASCIIZ encoding to detect the length of the incoming string: that means it deems the text to finish at the first NUL character.

This is not an error... when dealing with binary strings, you really need to keep both a `const char*` and `size_t` value from `.size()` (which you've effectively captured in `length`) in order to reconstruct the `string` like this:

```
std::string decompressionString(m_pcompCharptr, length);
```